# get_all_keys from folder within bucket on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I need some help on getting all the objects(keys) from a FOLDER within a bucket on Google Cloud Storage. Currently, I am executing the following in Python:

```
GOOGLE_STORAGE = 'gs'
src_uri = boto.storage_uri(base_bucket_name + '/' + userid, GOOGLE_STORAGE)

print 'this is the src_uri: %s' % src_uri

for key in src_uri.get_all_keys():
  print 'this is the key: %s' % key
```

And it returns:

```
this is the src_uri: gs://basebucket/user2
this is the key: <Key: basebucket,user1/key1>
this is the key: <Key: basebucket,user1/key2>
this is the key: <Key: basebucket,user1/key3>
this is the key: <Key: basebucket,user1/key4>
```

It is returning the entire list of keys within the bucket. Though it is possible to filter out the keys belonging to other users manually, that doesn't scale and there is surely a better way to do this. Let me know if you've had any experience with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [documentation for get_all_keys](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/gs.html#boto.gs.bucket.Bucket.get_all_keys), you need to pass the `prefix` and `delimiter` arguments.

However, I would suggest using the [list function](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/gs.html#boto.gs.bucket.Bucket.list) instead. Something like this should work:

```
bucket_uri = boto.storage_uri(base_bucket_name, GOOGLE_STORAGE)
for object_uri in bucket_uri.list_bucket(prefix='/%s' % userid, delimiter='/'):
    print object_uri
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It turns out that I needed an extra call get_bucket(), along with a prefix string for this to work: 'keys_for_userid = src_uri.get_bucket().get_all_keys(prefix=userid)'

Comment: I'm sure your method would work as well, I haven't tried it but it makes sense